# intelliJ is not recognising the Test annotation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, intellij-idea, automated-tests

Tried multiple ways but it is still having the same issue under maven. Also other Assert options are even not visible. Please help i am trying since 3 days.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5FmG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcTyI.jpg)

I tried by re-installing the maven.
Also tried the importing old as well as latest versions of TestNG still don't work.

Comment: Why do you have **both** testng and junit dependencies in your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

JUnit dependency has `test` scope configured by default. It means you can use it only in the classes under the [Test Sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#folder-categories) (`src/test/java`), not [Sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#folder-categories) (`src/main/java`)

Try to create test class under `src/test/java` and import JUnit class